# datetime attribute gets updated every time with datetime-picker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, datetime

I have a model that contains a `datetime` attribute, this attribute is filled in the form using the bootstrap-datetimepicker (http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/demo.php).

The problem is that every time I change something in the form and call the `update` controller, the attribute is seen as different and is updated by rails. 
Basically the attribute is updated in the DB even when it is not changed in the form.

I suppose it's a problem with the format I submit the date (which is a text field). I'm not sure about what format the text should be.

Here's some code:

the model

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :filled_date
end
```

the part of the html form for the datetime:

```
<div class="input-append date form_datetime">
  <input class="datetime_picker optional input-medium" id="visible_datetime" name="visible_datetime" type="text" value="16 Sep '13 - 18:45" disabled=""/>
</div>
<input class="datetime_picker optional input-medium" id="product_orders_attributes_0_filled_date" name="product[orders_attributes][0][filled_date]" size="30" type="hidden" value="2013-09-16 18:45" disabled="">
```

which is initialized with:

```
$(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({
      weekStart: 1
      daysOfWeekDisabled: [5,6]
      format: "dd M 'yy - hh:ii"
      autoclose: true
      pickerPosition: "bottom-left"
      todayBtn: true
      todayHighlight: true
      linkField: linkField
      linkFormat: "yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii"
})
```

I think it's the `linkFormat` here the part that I need to tweak in order to fix my issue.

Once clicked the form is sent as (it's a nested form):

```
"orders_attributes"=>
  {"0"=>
    {"filled_date"=>"2013-09-16 17:49",
     "_destroy"=>"",
     "id"=>"7"}},
```

This generates in the log a line like:

```
UPDATE "orders" SET "filled_date" = '2013-09-16 15:49:00.000000', "updated_at" = '2013-09-16 16:45:32.557340' WHERE "orders"."id" = 7
```

Any ideas?

thanks,

UPDATE:

investigating more, I found that rails internals work that they update anyways all the fields in the objects, and then the method `_field_changed?` is called on each to validate if it was changed or not.

the method looks like this in rails 3.2.14:

```
From: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/gems/activerecord-3.2.14/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb @ line 87 ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Dirty#_field_changed?:

    81: def _field_changed?(attr, old, value)
    82:   if column = column_for_attribute(attr)
    83:     if column.number? && (changes_from_nil_to_empty_string?(column, old, value) ||
    84:                           changes_from_zero_to_string?(old, value))
    85:       value = nil
    86:     else
 => 87:       value = column.type_cast(value)
    88:     end
    89:   end
    90: 
    91:   old != value
    92: end
```

and the reason why object seems to be updated every time I submit the for to the `update` controller is that old and value evaluate differently:

```
[2] pry(#<EntryOrder>)> old
=> Tue, 17 Sep 2013 01:49:00 CEST +02:00
[3] pry(#<EntryOrder>)> value
=> "2013-09-17 01:49:00"
[4] pry(#<EntryOrder>)> column.type_cast(value)
=> 2013-09-17 01:49:00 UTC
```

Namely old is in CEST, while value is interpreted as UTC.

now I got to figure out how to tell rails that the new value is in CEST as well.

any clue?

UPDATE2:

I've figured that `bootstrap-datetimepicker` lacks of support so switched to using two separate inputfields handled by [jquery-ui datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) and [jquery timepicker](https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker#timepicker-plugin-for-jquery). I've found that I have the same problem anyways, and tracked the issue down to rails 3.2.14 code, where there's probably a bug in the framework, which I reported [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12278).

I'm not sure there's a different way I'm supposed to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was fixed on the rails framework with this monkey patch https://gist.github.com/kennyj/6651773

the fix should be present in the next 3.2.14 version of rails.